# Does watir-webDriver support modal_dialogs created via Lightbox?

Tags: ruby, modal-dialog, watir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

Is the method modal_dialog supported by watir-webdriver? If not, is there another way for setting some text in a text field and clicking an ok button?

I've tried by putting

```
browser.modal_dialog.text_field(:name, "0.1.1.7.1.0.0.2.1.6.3.1").set(whatsNew)
```

but I keep getting the following error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `modal_dialog' for #<Watir::Browser:0x1026fa560>
```

I am Using Watir-Webdriver and the browser is Firefox.

This is the element I am trying to access:

```
<textarea onblur="document.getElementById('whatsNewinthisVersionUpdateSpinnerId').show();LCAjaxContainer.submitAndUpdate('whatsNewinthisVersionUpdateContainerId');" name="0.1.1.7.1.0.0.2.1.6.3.1">-Bug fixes</textarea>
```

Here is a link to more HTML: http://cl.ly/2k0M0z182w2H2O3v122Q

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure you are dealing with *modal* dialog? http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups

Comment: Just looked into it more and found out that it's a lightbox, which uses modal dialogs?...according to: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript))

Comment: Ok check link I just added into post

Comment: I have edited the post and added what I thought was relevant HTML.

Comment: updated title to include lightbox, which helps distinguish where the particular 'modal dialog' is coming from, and may be helpful for others with a similar issue finding the answer.

Comment: @Chuck van der Linden: approved your change. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
browser.text_field(:name, "0.1.1.7.1.0.0.2.1.6.3.1").set(whatsNew)
```

Comment: hmm yes it does! But I swear that was the first thing I tried and it didn't work lol. Thanks though!

Comment: another instance of the 'fake' modal popup it would appear.  Have to say I actually like these since once you realize what's going on, they are way easier to code around.